# TYPO3 tt_content with multipe elements 1:n

Tags: php, typo3

I have a problem: I want to have a custom `tt_content` with multiple entries, but when I want to store more than one item, I get an error: `2: SQL error: 'Data truncated for column 'personal_catalog_content_relation' at row 1' (tt_content:49)`

I think there are missing some foreign keys in the tables, but there isn't one in the tutorial I use. (https://learn-typo3.com/blog/news-detail/how-to-create-custom-content-elements-on-typo3)

Unlike in the tutorial, I only need the content and no additional settings. So I made some adjustments to the structure.

That is my result:

Making the `CType` available and defining the relationship between `tt_content` and `personal_catalog_content`:

Configuration/TCA/Overrides/tt_content.php

```
<?php

// Adds the content element to the "Type" dropdown
\TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\ExtensionManagementUtility::addTcaSelectItem(
   'tt_content',
   'CType',
    [
        // title
        'Personal Thumbnail',
        // plugin signature: extkey_identifier
        'personal_thumbnail',
        // icon identifier
        'content-text',
    ],
    'textmedia',
    'after'
);

// Configure the default backend fields for the content element
$GLOBALS['TCA']['tt_content']['types']['personal_thumbnail'] = [
   'showitem' => '
         --div--;LLL:EXT:core/Resources/Private/Language/Form/locallang_tabs.xlf:general,
            --palette--;;general,
            catalog-element; Elements,
         --palette--;--linebreak--,personal_catalog_content_relation,
         --div--;LLL:EXT:core/Resources/Private/Language/Form/locallang_tabs.xlf:access,
            --palette--;;hidden,
            --palette--;;access,
      ',
   'columnsOverrides' => [
      'bodytext' => [
         'config' => [
            'enableRichtext' => true,
            'richtextConfiguration' => 'default',
         ],
      ],
   ],
];

$personal_catalog_content = array(
  'personal_catalog_content_relation' => [
    'exclude' => 1,
    'label' => 'personal_catalog_content',
    'config' => [
      'type' => 'inline',
      'foreign_table' => 'personal_catalog_content',
      'appearance' => [
          'collapseAll' => 0,
          'levelLinksPosition' => 'top',
          'showSynchronizationLink' => 1,
          'showPossibleLocalizationRecords' => 1,
          'showAllLocalizationLink' => 1
      ],
    ],
  ],
);
\TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\ExtensionManagementUtility::addTCAcolumns('tt_content',$personal_catalog_content);
```

Here I just have an idea about what I am doing there. For some fields, I have no idea what they are doing. But I defined how one content element of n could be configured in the backend.

Configuration/TCA/personal_catalog_content.php

```
<?php
return [
    'ctrl' => [
        'title' => 'catalog_element',
        'label' => 'title',
        'sortby' => 'sorting',
        'tstamp' => 'tstamp',
        'crdate' => 'crdate',
        'cruser_id' => 'cruser_id',
        'versioningWS' => true,
        'languageField' => 'sys_language_uid',
        'transOrigPointerField' => 'l10n_parent',
        'translationSource' => 'l10n_source',
        'transOrigDiffSourceField' => 'l10n_diffsource',
        'delete' => 'deleted',
        'enablecolumns' => [
            'disabled' => 'hidden',
            'starttime' => 'starttime',
            'endtime' => 'endtime',
        ],
        'searchFields' => 'title,sub_title,image,hyperlink',
        // 'iconfile' => 'EXT:your_extension_key/Resources/Public/Icons/ContentElements/header_with_title.svg'
    ],
    'interface' => [
        'showRecordFieldList' => 'sys_language_uid, l10n_parent, l10n_diffsource, hidden, hyperlink, title, sub_title, image',
    ],
    'palettes' => [
        'catalog_item_0' => [
            'showitem' => '
                sys_language_uid,
                l10n_parent,
                l10n_diffsource,
                hidden,
            ',
        ],
    ],
    'types' => [
        '1' => ['showitem' => '
            --palette--;TEST_PALETTE,
            hyperlink, title, sub_title, image,
            --div--;LLL:EXT:frontend/Resources/Private/Language/locallang_ttc.xlf:tabs.access, starttime, endtime'
        ],
    ],
    'columns' => [
        'sys_language_uid' => [
            'exclude' => true,
            'label' => 'LLL:EXT:lang/locallang_general.xlf:LGL.language',
            'config' => [
                'type' => 'select',
                'renderType' => 'selectSingle',
                'special' => 'languages',
                'items' => [
                    [
                        'LLL:EXT:lang/locallang_general.xlf:LGL.allLanguages',
                        -1,
                        'flags-multiple'
                    ]
                ],
                'default' => 0,
            ],
        ],
        'l10n_parent' => [
            'displayCond' => 'FIELD:sys_language_uid:>:0',
            'exclude' => true,
            'label' => 'LLL:EXT:lang/locallang_general.xlf:LGL.l18n_parent',
            'config' => [
                'type' => 'select',
                'renderType' => 'selectSingle',
                'default' => 0,
                'items' => [
                    ['', 0],
                ],
                'foreign_table' => 'personal_catalog_content',
                'foreign_table_where' => 'AND personal_catalog_content.pid=###CURRENT_PID### AND personal_catalog_content.sys_language_uid IN (-1,0)',
            ],
        ],
        'l10n_diffsource' => [
            'config' => [
                'type' => 'passthrough',
            ],
        ],
        't3ver_label' => [
            'label' => 'LLL:EXT:lang/locallang_general.xlf:LGL.versionLabel',
            'config' => [
                'type' => 'input',
                'size' => 30,
                'max' => 255,
            ],
        ],
        'hidden' => [
            'exclude' => true,
            'label' => 'LLL:EXT:lang/locallang_general.xlf:LGL.hidden',
            'config' => [
                'type' => 'check',
                'items' => [
                    '1' => [
                        '0' => 'LLL:EXT:lang/Resources/Private/Language/locallang_core.xlf:labels.enabled'
                    ]
                ],
            ],
        ],
        'starttime' => [
            'exclude' => true,
            'behaviour' => [
                'allowLanguageSynchronization' => true
            ],
            'label' => 'LLL:EXT:lang/locallang_general.xlf:LGL.starttime',
            'config' => [
                'type' => 'input',
                'renderType' => 'inputDateTime',
                'size' => 13,
                'eval' => 'datetime',
                'default' => 0,
            ],
        ],
        'endtime' => [
            'exclude' => true,
            'behaviour' => [
                'allowLanguageSynchronization' => true
            ],
            'label' => 'LLL:EXT:lang/locallang_general.xlf:LGL.endtime',
            'config' => [
                'type' => 'input',
                'renderType' => 'inputDateTime',
                'size' => 13,
                'eval' => 'datetime',
                'default' => 0,
                'range' => [
                    'upper' => mktime(0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 2038)
                ],
            ],
        ],
        /*'dark_mode' => [
            'exclude' => true,
            'label' => 'LLL:EXT:your_extension_key/Resources/Private/Language/locallang.xlf:foundation_slider_content.dark_mode',
            'config' => [
                'type' => 'check',
                'items' => [
                    '1' => [
                        '0' => 'LLL:EXT:lang/Resources/Private/Language/locallang_core.xlf:labels.enabled'
                    ]
                ],
                'default' => 0,
            ]
        ],*/
        'title' => [
            'exclude' => true,
            'label' => 'Title',
            'config' => [
                'type' => 'input',
                'size' => 30,
                'eval' => 'trim'
            ],
        ],
        'sub_title' => [
            'exclude' => true,
            'label' => 'Sub Title',
            'config' => [
                'type' => 'text',
                'enableRichtext' => true,
                'richtextConfiguration' => 'default',
                'fieldControl' => [
                    'fullScreenRichtext' => [
                        'disabled' => false,
                    ],
                ],
                'cols' => 40,
                'rows' => 15,
                'eval' => 'trim',
            ],

        ],
        'image' => [
            'exclude' => true,
            'label' => 'Image',
            'config' => \TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\ExtensionManagementUtility::getFileFieldTCAConfig(
                'image',
                [
                    'appearance' => [
                        'createNewRelationLinkTitle' => 'LLL:EXT:frontend/Resources/Private/Language/locallang_ttc.xlf:images.addFileReference'
                    ],
                    'overrideChildTca' => [
                        'types' => [
                            '0' => [
                                'showitem' => '
                                --palette--;LLL:EXT:lang/locallang_tca.xlf:sys_file_reference.imageoverlayPalette;imageoverlayPalette,
                                --palette--;;filePalette'
                            ],
                            \TYPO3\CMS\Core\Resource\File::FILETYPE_TEXT => [
                                'showitem' => '
                                --palette--;LLL:EXT:lang/locallang_tca.xlf:sys_file_reference.imageoverlayPalette;imageoverlayPalette,
                                --palette--;;filePalette'
                            ],
                            \TYPO3\CMS\Core\Resource\File::FILETYPE_IMAGE => [
                                'showitem' => '
                                --palette--;LLL:EXT:lang/locallang_tca.xlf:sys_file_reference.imageoverlayPalette;imageoverlayPalette,
                                --palette--;;filePalette'
                            ],
                            \TYPO3\CMS\Core\Resource\File::FILETYPE_AUDIO => [
                                'showitem' => '
                                --palette--;LLL:EXT:lang/locallang_tca.xlf:sys_file_reference.imageoverlayPalette;imageoverlayPalette,
                                --palette--;;filePalette'
                            ],
                            \TYPO3\CMS\Core\Resource\File::FILETYPE_VIDEO => [
                                'showitem' => '
                                --palette--;LLL:EXT:lang/locallang_tca.xlf:sys_file_reference.imageoverlayPalette;imageoverlayPalette,
                                --palette--;;filePalette'
                            ],
                            \TYPO3\CMS\Core\Resource\File::FILETYPE_APPLICATION => [
                                'showitem' => '
                                --palette--;LLL:EXT:lang/locallang_tca.xlf:sys_file_reference.imageoverlayPalette;imageoverlayPalette,
                                --palette--;;filePalette'
                            ],
                        ],
                    ],
                    'maxitems' => 1
                ],
                $GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']['GFX']['imagefile_ext']
            ),
        ],
        'hyperlink' => [
            'exclude' => true,
            'label' => 'Hyperlink',
            'config' => [
                'type' => 'input',
                'renderType' => 'inputLink',
            ],
        ],
    ],
];
```

Creating the tables in the database

ext_tables.sql

```
#
# Add SQL definition of database tables
#

CREATE TABLE tt_content (
        personal_catalog_content_relation int(11) unsigned DEFAULT '0'
);


CREATE TABLE personal_catalog_content (
        uid int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
        pid int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
        t3ver_oid int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
        tstamp int(11) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',

        personal_catalog_content_relation int(11) unsigned DEFAULT '0' NOT NULL,

        title varchar(255) DEFAULT 'Title' NOT NULL,
        sub_title varchar(255) DEFAULT 'Sub Title' NOT NULL,
        image int(11) unsigned NOT NULL default '0',
        hyperlink varchar(255) DEFAULT 'Hyperlink' NOT NULL,

        sorting int(11) DEFAULT '0' NOT NULL,
        
        PRIMARY KEY (`uid`),
);
```

Make the tables available to all standard pages:

ext_tables.php

```
<?php
defined('TYPO3') or die('Access denied.');

\TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\ExtensionManagementUtility::allowTableOnStandardPages('
      personal_catalog_content,
');
```

Here you can see the error. I can store one element, but I get the error if I want to store a second element.

[image: Error while storing]

Can you help me? Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For 1:n relations you have to define a parent field and add to TCA.
As I see, you have already personal_catalog_content_relation defined in your child table.
Go into tt_content and change to following:

```php
    $personal_catalog_content = array(
       'personal_catalog_content_relation' => [
       'exclude' => 1,
       'label' => 'personal_catalog_content',
       'config' => [
           'type' => 'inline',
           'foreign_table' => 'personal_catalog_content',
           'foreign_field' => 'personal_catalog_content_relation',
           'appearance' => [
                  'collapseAll' => 0,
                  'levelLinksPosition' => 'top',
                  'showSynchronizationLink' => 1,
                  'showPossibleLocalizationRecords' => 1,
                  'showAllLocalizationLink' => 1
            ],
          ],
        ],
    );
```

Otherwise TYPO3 tries to save the uids of your relations in comma separated string, which doesn't fit with table field defined as integer, which causes your error.

Comment: Do I understand it correctly if I read that as a kind of foreign key definition

Comment: Yes, your'e right. The foreign_field keeps the uid of the related table, but without having foreign_key set in database. This is a failure in TYPO3, but doesn't make any problems